# Cannot display any data from firestore flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, mobile, google-cloud-firestore

i am developing a flutter mobile apps and i have encountered few error. which is when im running my apps, the data is not displayed. I try to retrieve the uid and specific field to be display. This is the code for the retrieve part
[image]

and this is my database where i want to retrieve the type of the user database.

[image]

This is the output from my apps output

[image]

Comment: collection("User") used two times, not to use the second time.

Comment: @JahidulIslam That is still valid hes just calling another instance. But it just boilerplate code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67188227/how-to-call-firebase-firestore-specific-document-id-in-flutter-and-specific-fiel/67189271?noredirect=1#comment118792121_67189271
bro you have to tell what SDK you are using , web/android_java/flutter. and this code will not work coz , for loop doesnt work well with async task

Answer (score 0):

Change your query to this.

```
    firestore
        .collection("User")
        .where("uid", isEqualTo: result.id)
        .where("type", isEqualTo: "teacher")
        .get();
```

Comment: Still the same the output still no data

Answer (score 0):

```
     void getTeacherData(){
            firestore
            .collection("User")
            .where("type", isEqualTo: "teacher")
            .get().then((querySnapshot){
             //Check here if not null
              querySnapshot.docs.forEach((element){
                print(element["name"]);
                });
             }); 
}
```

this will give you all the user who are teachers

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage/#querying) documentation, your query should be as follows:

```
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

Future getTeacherData() async {
  firestore
      .collection('User')
      .where('type', isEqualTo: 'teacher')
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.docs.forEach((result) {
              print(result['uid']);
          });
      });
}
```

Please tell us if this worked for you.